# Limit Compass to watch only a specific part of my scss

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, compass

I don't know if anyone has ever had the same struggle as me : **the time to compile your scss to css can become too long!**

I'm working on a project over a theme/template. I need to override it but sometimes I still need it and I have to edit it.

So my question is pretty basic and I haven't found an answer yet; I don't want my `compass watch` to watch the whole file but only, let say, the first 5000 lines.

Is there a way of doing it?